# How to sort google sheet columns based on string matching?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 3 fields key1, key2, and value in the google sheet. I want to sort key2 and value based on key1 field which has all the keys of column key2 but in a different order. So that key2 and value will be in the same order of key1 and for all the rows `key1 = key2` satisfies.

Is there any way to do this?

Example:

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: This question needs some clarification. Please see this link: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JPV i have updated question with example. Is it now clear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example given (and assuming the data is in columns A:C), you could try

```
=ArrayFormula({A1:C1;  A2:A , iferror(VLOOKUP(A2:A, B:C, {1,2}, 0))})
```

Depending on your locale, you may have to use:

```
=ArrayFormula({A1:C1;  A2:A \ iferror(VLOOKUP(A2:A; B:C; {1\2}; 0))})
```

[image]